# Is it ok to retain and autorelease at the same time?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have the following code:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *items;
}
@end


@implementation MyClass

-(Item *)getItem
{
    if(items.count < 1)
    {
        [self buildItemsArray];
    }
    Item *item =  [[[items objectAtIndex:0]retain]autorelease];
    [items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    return item;
}

-(void)buildItemsArray
{
    // ...
    [items addItem:someNewItem];
    [items addItem:someOtherNewItem];
}
@end
```

I have a function that returns an item. If the items go down to 0, then the items array is built again inside buildItemsArray. My game logic requires that when I return an item, I need to remove it from the array. So, I am using a retain to ensure that the item is valid till the return line (since the only other known retain happened when the item was added to the items array), and an autorelease to ensure it gets cleaned up later. I have checked that this code neither crashes nor leaks. I wonder if:

a) This is OK - the reason I ask is that I have predominantly seen code with alloc/init/autorelease, and haven't run into this case with retain/autorelease
b) Is there some reason to alloc/init/autorelease instead:

```
Item *item =  [[Item alloc]initWithItem:[items objectAtIndex:0]autorelease];
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not ok because at this day and age you should be using ARC and wouldn't have had this question to begin with. Just sayin' :)

Comment: agree with using ARC those days, but for learning i think it is essential to understand how this works anyway.

Comment: We are going to ARC, but wanted to fix existing leaks before doing it, just so we understand how it works.

Comment: @anand, Hi, I'm also facing a similar issue, and I wonder what it means to set ARC on ? I thought it activated automatically unless otherwise stated. if not, perhaps you can tell me how to activate ARC, and how to set `Item *item` in this case ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally ok:

```
Item *item = [[[items objectAtIndex:0] retain] autorelease];
[items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
return item;
```

Though this would make the intent clearer (returning an autoreleased object):

```
Item *item = [[items objectAtIndex:0] retain];
[items removeObject:item];
return [item autorelease];
```

No reason to alloc/init. That just adds unnecessary overhead.

Like I said in my comment, if this is a (relatively) new project, you really really really should be using ARC and not worry about these things anymore.

Comment: Agreed - will be doing ARC (in fact, already have it all tested and tried) - wanted to fix leaks before doing ARC just to understand...